# Determine if Zebra is installed in ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

What command line should be use to determine if zebra is installed in my ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo update-rc.d koha-zebra-daemon defaults
```

Comment: System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/koha-zebra-daemon already exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Koha [since 3.18](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/PackagesIndexDaemon) there is a [Zebra service/daemon](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_Debian#Services) for background record indexing, over Systemd.

Try:

```
systemctl status koha-common
```

[Or `koha-zebra`](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Commands_provided_by_the_Debian_packages#koha-zebra):

```
sudo koha-zebra --status INSTANCE
```